# WCF и не стабильная сеть

Tags: сеть, wcf

Есть сервер с WCF сервисом - хостится под IIS 7.

Порядка 40 клиентов каждую минуту либо выкачивают файлы либо их аплоадят. 
Выкачивают побольше, аплоад значительно меньших размеров - порядка 3-4Кб zip.

До недавнего времени все было отлично. Сейчас же что-то случилось с сетью (сеть в масштабах страны - дальше подробностей не знаю) и аплоады валятся с таймаутами (стоит минута по умолчанию). После большого кол-ва попыток аплоад все таки проходит.

Админы признают что с сетью есть проблемы но в заявленных нами условиях (ширина канала) они укладываются и как бы формально претензий к ним нет. Либо говорят дайте инструментальное средство, которое покажет какие еще требования нужно предъявить к соединению с сервером и они не выполняются и тогда они устранят проблемы.

Биндинг, кстати, NetTcpBinding.

Так как я от сетей далек, да и сеть чужая, то вопрос : 
что есть из каких-либо средств показывающих более детально проблему таймаута?

Я слышал от админов проскочила фраза про фрагментированные пакеты и поиск в гугле показал что WCF так или иначе использует 3 запроса для передачи одного пакета - может в этом проблема?

Может где-то есть гайд требований к сети для корректной работы WCF сервисов?

Answer (score 2):

1. По поводу требований к админам можно сказать про QoS в плане вероятности потери пакета/ошибки доступа. В передаче информации есть термин обозначающий вероятность ошибочного приема символа или бита (часто от 10^-6) - но это очень дорогое удовольствие (админы, так понимаю, VPN Вашей организации).
2. Если есть возможность использования тестовых клиентов или машины боевых клиентов - попробуйте сниффер (Wireshark, например, вроде с VPN через вируальный адаптер можно смотреть трафик) и сопоставьте с тем что было на выходе и что на входе.

Вполне вероятно, что при длительном взаимодействии могут возникать проблемы при передаче пакетов на уровне IP - маршруты могут меняться. Наблюдал ситуацию когда хвост приходил раньше головы.

Answer (score 2):

Советую пересмотреть используемый транспортный стэк. Посмотрите в отладчике из каких элементов состоит ваш биндинг (`new NetTcpBinding().CreateBindingElements()`). Конечно же, они все нужны... иногда. Можно попробовать выкинуть лишние, собрав свой `cutsomBinding`. Все-таки, 3 запроса на 1 сообщение - это много, если я правильно понял о чем речь.

Обязательно поиграйтесь с тайм-аутами, особенно с тайм-аутом на чтение. Иногда даже получасовое ожидание прихода сообщения бывает предпочтительнее, чем разрыв связи. Иногда - наоборот. Не забывайте, что у каждой стороны - свои тайм-ауты, и они не обязательно должны совпадать.

Что же насчет диагностических утилит - попробуйте обычный `ping`, указав ему ключом `-l` размер пакета равный размеру вашего обычного WCF-сообщения (посмотреть его можно через Wireshark).

Comment: Дело в том что я про 3 запроса узнал погуглив как устроен это самый NetTcpBinding. Сами мы 3-х запросов не посылаем и даже более того не создаем биндинги вручную. Все что сгенерила Visual Studio то и используем, а биндинги исключительно через конфиг настраиваем. Попробую через Wireshark определить размеры и пинг. Спасибо

Comment: `customBinding` тоже через конфиг создается и настраивается. Отладчик я упомянул лишь как способ узнать, что внутри у `netTcpBinding`